# sql union returns duplicate results

Tags: sql, union

I have the following query

```
select count(trade_sid), shortcode 
from  trade 
where 
    trade.trade_date <= sysdate and 
    trade.trade_date>= add_months(sysdate, -11) 
group by shortcode
UNION ALL
select count(trade_sid), shortcode 
from trade_archive 
where 
    trade_archive.trade_date <= sysdate and 
    trade_archive.trade_date>= add_months(sysdate, -11) 
group by shortcode
order by shortcode
```

This reults in duplicate output like this

```
23 abc
24 abc 
56 def
87 def
```

This is because of the union operator which is used, any idea how I can change this query so that i get

```
47 abc
143 def
```

as the output

The user with which i finally execute this query in java does not have sufficient privileges to create temp tables is there any other way of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select count(trade_sid), shortcode 
from
(
    select trade_sid, shortcode 
    from  trade 
    where 
        trade.trade_date <= sysdate and 
        trade.trade_date>= add_months(sysdate, -11) 
    UNION ALL
    select trade_sid, shortcode 
    from trade_archive 
    where 
        trade_archive.trade_date <= sysdate and 
        trade_archive.trade_date>= add_months(sysdate, -11) 
) tt
group by shortcode
order by shortcode
```

Answer (score 0):

You must sum the values and group by the shortcode, like this:

```
select sum(count(trade_sid)), shortcode 
from  trade 
where 
    trade.trade_date <= sysdate and 
    trade.trade_date>= add_months(sysdate, -11) 
group by shortcode
UNION ALL
select count(trade_sid), shortcode 
from trade_archive 
where 
    trade_archive.trade_date <= sysdate and 
    trade_archive.trade_date>= add_months(sysdate, -11) 
group by shortcode
order by shortcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION`, not `UNION ALL`.

union returns distinct records.

The only problem is that your rows are not the same.

Comment: This will not work. If you have two sets `23 abc` and `23 abc`, union will result in `23 abc`, while result should be `46 abc`. Also changing `union all` with `union` will take no effect on the data shown in the example.